# EmberJS-Adding dynamic data-attributes inside handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template, an associated view and a relevant controller. The template just loops over an array of objects and render a list of divs. I need to add a data-project-id attribute for each of this div (id is a property of objects in the model).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="projects">
    {{#each project in model}}
        <div data-project-id={{project.Id}}>
            // Do something
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

App.ProjectsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'projects',
    attributeBindings: ['data-project-id'],
    'data-project-id': function() {
        return this.content.Id;
     }.property('content.id')
}
```

However, 'content' inside the view is currently undefined. What is the best way to add this dynamic attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind-attr` to bind the data attribute to a model property:

```
{{#each project in model}}
    <div {{bind-attr data-projet-id='project.Id'}}>
        // Do something
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/

Comment: Haha, I didn't even try using the bind-attr helper as the same page you referenced above says "By default, view helpers do not accept data attributes". My mistake. Some examples are referencing the template in the View object using the templateName property while some are using the 'View' helper. Are these both the similar? I saw a couple of examples where a model is accessed inside a view using the 'content' property but for me it is returning undefined.

Comment: The view helpers won't accept data bindings, but you should be able to bind to a div as shown in my example code.